# Cannot fetch from git in Team City 8.1.2

Tags: git, teamcity

I am running Team City 8.1.2 on windows 7 with a single Agent on the same machine as the server. Both the agent and server are running under an account that has access to my Git Repo.

I have created a job with Git VCS and selected:

**VCS checkout mode:** Automatically on agent (if supported by VCS roots)

But as a result it just hangs when running the git fetch:

```
[16:12:49][VCS Root: git] Commit '092a67f48d5bdbfaf946e1ed93bdcb81d6e373b0' is not found in repository. Running 'git fetch'...
```

Now if I instead choose:

**VCS checkout mode:** Automatically on server

It works.

How do I get it to work on the agent?